# How do I create closure around the data acted upon by C# 4.0 tasks?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm encrypting data in chunks.  I'm passing each chunk of data to a Task like yay:

```
private static Task<string> EncryptChunk( byte[] buffer, CryptoEngine c )
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult( c.Encrypt( buffer ) );
    } );
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

As I debug in the code that calls this method I can see that it's passing proper chunks as the buffer parameter.  If I set a breakpoint inside StartNew above, however, I see that the buffer is always the last buffer encountered by the main thread.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the calling code, including the creation of `buffer`.

Comment: Does each `EncryptChunk` call get passed a different `byte[]` or are they all being passed the same array reference?

Comment: Side note: Why not just `return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => c.Encrypt(buffer));` and do away with the `TaskCompletionSource` altogether?

Comment: @Cameron: I just added that to my answer too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you're reusing the same byte array. The *parameter* will be captured - but in this case as nothing in your method captures the parameter, it's effectively capturing the reference. If you want to be able to reuse the original array (i.e. populate it with new data) but still read the old data within the task, you need to make a copy of the data. e.g.

```
private static Task<string> EncryptChunk( byte[] buffer, CryptoEngine c )
{
    buffer = buffer.ToArray(); // Copy the data
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult( c.Encrypt( buffer ) );
    } );
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

As an aside, why are you using `TaskCompletionSource` here, instead of just:

```
return Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => c.Encrypt(buffer));
```

or using type inference:

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => c.Encrypt(buffer));
```

Comment: Is `ToArray` better than `Clone` here?

Comment: @Gabe: Not particularly. No cast required, that's all :) Probably slower, mind you.

Comment: duh - need to make deep copy.  Sorry for stupid question.  Will also use type inference method.